# Error with TypeScript syntax: declarative array with methods

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem with TypeScript syntax in my Angular 4 project.
If I create a normal class, such as:

```
export class MyClass {
  field1: string;
  field2: number;
  field3: boolean;

  myMethod() {
   this.field2 = this.field2 + 2;
  }
}
```

I can't declare an array of MyClass elements with this syntax:

```
myclassarray: MyClass[] = [{
  field1: 'hello',
  field2: 3,
  field3: false
}];
```

Because in my class there is an instance method and not a static method.
The question is: how can I declare an array of elements that also include non-static methods  that are useful to me?

I also don't understand the syntax that allows you to initialize these items in a declarative way.

Comment: What's stopping you from using a static method?

Comment: because I want methods that modify the data fields of my class instance

Comment: Is it language issue or your problem not understanding principles of OOP? If you need array of objects with methods - you maust use `new MyClass()` syntax. If you want to initialize properties - use constructor. If you have "too many" properties - use constructor that accepts interface (`constructor(dto: MyClassInterface){ this = Object.assign({}, dto);}`).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to assign the object literal to an instance of `MyClass`:

```
myclassarray: MyClass[] = [
    Object.assign(new MyClass(), {
        field1: 'hello',
        field2: 3,
        field3: false
    })
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a class, why not use a constructor?

```js
class MyClass {
    constructor(public field1: string, public field2: number, public field3: boolean) {}

    myMethod() {
        this.field2 = this.field2 + 2;
    }

    show() {
        console.log(this.field2);
    }
}

let myclassarray = new MyClass(
    'hello', 3, false
);
```

You can then call them like so:

```js
myclassarray.myMethod();
myclassarray.show(); // logs 5
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to create object of MyClass first and then intialize values then push into array.

```
myclassarray: Array<MyClass> = [];
myClass: MyClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.field1 ='';
    myClass.field2 =1;
    myClass.field3 = false;


myclassarray.push(myClass);
```